# How to make path a hyperlink with space in path using powershell

Tags: powershell, hyperlink

I am using a powershell script I created to email a user when files are received in a folder. The problem I am having is some of the folder paths that are being watched have a space in the path breaking the hyperlink in the email body sent.  How can I include the space so it doesn't break the hyperlink.

I use this to get the pathname:

```
$(split-path $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath)
```

The code to add to the body of the email I am using is below:

```
$global:newFiles.Add("`n[$(Get-Date -Format HH:mm:ss)]`tNew file named $($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name) arrived in $(split-path $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath) and was copied to $($dPath)\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy'))\$((Get-Date).ToString('MMM yyyy'))\$((Get-Date).AddDays(1 + $(1,2 -eq 7 - [int]$formatteddate.dayofweek) ).ToString('MMM d yyyy'))")
```

Here is how the email is sent:

```
while ($watcher.EnableRaisingEvents -or $global:newFiles.Count -gt 0) {   

#Sleep
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60

if($global:newFiles.Count -gt 0) {
    #Convert list of strings to single string (multiline)
    $smtpbody = $global:newFiles 

    $smtp.Send($smtpFrom, $smtpTo, $smtpSubject, $smtpBody) 

    #Mail sent, Empty array
    $global:newFiles.Clear()
}
```

}

Comment: Can you give a filename example?  Your code doesn't really help (also, it looks pretty convoluted with multiple `Get-Date` calls)

Comment: This is how the body of the email looks: `[11:51:26]      New file named Test Claim 40791826 072117 Coversheet.pdf arrived in \\vavm\FTP\K NW\Incoming and was copied to M:\H_Audits\Original Bills\2017\Aug 2017\Aug 31 2017 ` the link shows as **\\vavm\FTP\K** instead of **\\vavm\FTP\K NW\Incoming**

Comment: What method are you using to create/send the email?  `Send-MailMessage`?

Comment: the issue is not sending the email its the link

Comment: Doesn't mean they're not related.  I don't see any HTML tags or anything to imply the text is a hyperlink.

Comment: outlook automatically converts this to a hyperlink

Comment: Not sure why the down vote, seems like a good question as it can't be answered correclty.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was able to simply fix this by adding a open and closed chevron around the path name.`<$(split-path $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath)>`

Full line of code below:

```
$global:newFiles.Add("`n[$(Get-Date -Format HH:mm:ss)]`tNew file named $($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name) arrived in <$(split-path $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath)>  and was copied to $($dPath)\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy'))\$((Get-Date).ToString('MMM yyyy'))\$((Get-Date).AddDays(1 + $(1,2 -eq 7 - [int]$formatteddate.dayofweek) ).ToString('MMM d yyyy'))")
```

Answer (score 1):

As TheIncorrigible1 mentioned you are missing the HTML tags to tell Outlook that this is a hyperlinkg:

```
$Body = "<a href='\\vavm\FTP\K NW\Incoming'>\\vavm\FTP\K NW\Incoming</a>"
Send-MailMessage -To $MailTo -SmtpServer $MailServer -From $MailFrom -Body $MailBody -BodyAsHtml -Subject $MailSubject
```

Comment: As I mentioned before Outlook will automatically convert Text with a path filename, but if it has a space it will be truncated at the first space. Also I have hundreds of folders that are being watched. I tried adding the href link before as it does not work.